# Who owns Dumbledore's wand?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, wandlore

During the Battle of Hogwarts, Voldemort found that the Elder Wand, which he had taken from Dumbledore's tomb, was not working as impressively as he had hoped. Believing that this was because Snape had its allegiance after killing Dumbledore, Voldemort had Nagini kill Snape.

When he and Harry faced off shortly afterwards, Harry corrected him: since Draco had disarmed Dumbledore, he was the true master of the Elder Wand, not Snape. When Harry disarmed Draco in Malfoy Manor,he was having a different wand in his hand.

**Then how the Elder Wand's allegiance shifted to Harry Potter ?** In case the Elder Wand's allegiance shifted to Harry potter,  when Voldemort used killing spell on Harry at forbidden forest, the wand's  allegiance should have shifted to Voldemort. **Why didn't the Elder Wand's allegiance shift to Voldemort?**

Comment: Dumbledore....?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying - in a sense Voldemort defeated Harry in the Forbidden Forest, so why didn't he regain mastery of the wand? I think the point is that Harry didn't try to defend himself and so no wands sensed that weakness of defeat.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that the Elder Wand's allegiance only shifts to a victorious wizard if that wizard is capable of accepting death. Such a restriction would of course prevent Voldemort from _ever_ truly owning the Elder Wand.